# protractor ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement returns false when the expected message has mora than one line

Tags: selenium, protractor

I'm facing a new problem with protractor , 
When I try to use this selenium method:

> ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement

It is returning false because my element returns this messsage:
Connection Unavailable.
Could not connect to the equipment at this time

This is my expected string:

> message : Connection Unavailable.\nCould not connect to equipment at this time

then my method call is:

```
browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(element, message), 160000, 'The expected text is not present in the UI');
```

Maybe somebody can help me with it

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's not the best approach, but it'll solve your problem. Simply replace your expected messages with ones that have no `\n`:

```
browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(element, message.replaceAll("\\n", " ")), 
             160000, 'The expected text is not present in the UI');
```

Comment: This is actually the best approach; another approach is to search for keywords that need to be in the text like "connection unavailable" and then assume the rest of the message is correct or search for "equipment" as well. But those would require different matchers instead of `textToBePresentInElement`)

Comment: Wich another macthers ? Could you give me examples ? 

Thanks